# Set image as wallpaper from url (Glide + json)

Tags: java, android, set, android-glide, wallpaper

[app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oTXf.jpg)
[app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSRXV.jpg)

Hi, thanks in advance to those who guide me.

I have a problem with the Set Wallpaper, that when I clicked on the button, I get the following error:

2018-12-28 22: 36: 02.801 13030-13030 /? E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress (android.graphics.Bitmap $ CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

I leave the files used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail2"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtclose"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circulo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/equis"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                android:layout_width="159dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/borde_redondo"
                android:text="Establecer como Fondo de Pantalla"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

public class infoanimales extends AppCompatActivity {

```
        private RequestOptions options;
        TextView txtclose;
        LinearLayout img;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_infoanimales);

            Button button = findViewById(R.id.btn);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setWallpaper();
                }
            });

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }

            this.options = new RequestOptions()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC);

            String image_url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("img2");

            img = findViewById(R.id.thumbnail2);
            Glide.with(this).load(image_url).into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable fondoreceta, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        img.setBackground(fondoreceta);
                    }
                }
            });

            TextView txtclose = findViewById(R.id.txtclose);
            txtclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    finish();
                }
            });
        }

        private void setWallpaper() {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("img2");
            WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

            try {
                manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Listo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

With this function, it works perfect, but that is having the images in the drawable folder, and what you want or what it is that you take the image of the json url, traide with glide

```
private void setWallpaper() {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cochinito);
        WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        try {
            manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Listo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

In conclusion, what I need is that when you click on the button, the displayed image is set as wallpaper

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are not using full path for decoding bitmap. You need to obtain full path name like:

```
String uri =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + PHOTO_DIR  + "/test.jpg";
```

After that:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri);
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String))

Comment: Hi Aykut.

I made your change, and when I clicked the button, the app closed, and the log showed me the following:

java.lang.NullPointerException: on a null object reference
com.vinotintoplayer.wallpaperhd4k.infoanimales.setWallpaper(infoanimales.java:87)

try {
            manager.setBitmap(bitmap); <--- Java:87

Answer (score 0):

Set wallpaper with Glide4+ I did like this:

```
public void setAsWallpaper() {
            Glide.with(requireContext())
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(listItem.get(position).getWallpaperImage())
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
    
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
    
                            try {
                                WallpaperManager.getInstance(requireContext()).setBitmap(resource);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).